# Determine whether Python object is regex or string

Tags: python, regex

Thought exercise: What is the "best" way to write a Python function that takes a regex pattern *or* a string to match exactly:

```
import re
strings = [...]

def do_search(matcher):
  """
  Returns strings matching matcher, which can be either a string
  (for exact match) or a compiled regular expression object
  (for more complex matches).
  """
  if not is_a_regex_pattern(matcher):
    matcher = re.compile('%s$' % re.escape(matcher))

  for s in strings:
    if matcher.match(s):
      yield s
```

So, ideas for the implementation of `is_a_regex_pattern()`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can access the `_sre.SRE_Pattern` type via `re._pattern_type`:

```
if not isinstance(matcher, re._pattern_type):
    matcher = re.compile('%s$' % re.escape(matcher))
```

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> import re
>>> re._pattern_type
<class '_sre.SRE_Pattern'>
>>> isinstance(re.compile('abc'), re._pattern_type)
True
>>>
```

Comment: Note that this broke on Python 3.7, where it was renamed to `re.Pattern`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66957786/895245

Answer (score 1):

Or, make it [quack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17029047/673991):

```
try:
    does_match = matcher.match(s)
except AttributeError:
    does_match = re.match(matcher.s)

if does_match:
    yield s
```

In other words, treat `matcher` as if it already were a **compiled regular expression**. And if that breaks, then treat it like a **string** that needs to be compiled.

This is called [Duck Typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).  Not everyone [agrees](https://stackoverflow.com/a/839844/673991) that exceptions should be used like this for routine contingencies.  This is the [ask-permission versus ask-forgiveness](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/02/06/write-cleaner-python-use-exceptions/) debate.  Python is more [amenable](https://docs.python.org/faq/design.html#how-fast-are-exceptions) to forgiveness than most languages.

Answer (score 0):

1. Not a string:

   ```
   def is_a_regex_pattern(s):
     return not isinstance(s, basestring)
   ```
2. Is a `_sre.SRE_Pattern` (though that's not importable, so use a gross string match):

   ```
   def is_a_regex_pattern(s):
     return s.__class__.__name__ == 'SRE_Pattern'
   ```
3. You can re-compile a SRE_Pattern and it *seems* to evaluate the same.

   ```
   def is_a_regex_pattern(s):
     return s == re.compile(s)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You could test, if `matcher` has an method `match`:

```
import re

def do_search(matcher, strings):
    """
    Returns strings matching matcher, which can be either a string
    (for exact match) or a compiled regular expression object
    (for more complex matches).
    """
    if hasattr(matcher, 'match'):
        test = matcher.match
    else:
        test = lambda s: matcher==s

    for s in strings:
        if test(s):
            yield s
```

You should not use global variables, but use a second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

**On Python 3.7, `re._pattern_type` was renamed to `re.Pattern`**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27366172/895245 therefore broke at that point, as `re._pattern_type`  is not defined.

While `re.Pattern` looks nicer and will therefore hopefully be more stable, it is not mentioned at all in the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-objects so maybe it is not a good idea to rely on it.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46779329/895245 does make some sense. But what is someday the `str` class adds a `.match` method and it does something completely different? :-) Ah, the joys of typeless languages.

So I think I'm going with:

```
import re

_takes_s_or_re_type = type(re.compile(''))
def takes_s_or_re(s_or_re):
    if isinstance(s_or_re, _takes_s_or_re_type):
        return 0
    else:
        return 1

assert takes_s_or_re(re.compile('a.c')) == 0
assert takes_s_or_re('a.c') == 1
```

as this can only break when a public API breaks.

Tested on Python 3.8.0.